# Error 'Invalid values[1][0]: list_value' when i try append numbers to a list in Python and send that list to a Google Sheets column

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

My list to send to spreadsheet via Python is:

```
para_enviar_conjunto = [[21], [79]]
```

This list is created on this code (I didn't add the sheet id because I tried to preserve this piece of code):

```
import requests
from Google import Create_Service

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"
    }

CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secrets.json'
API_NAME = 'sheets'
API_VERSION = 'v4'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
service = Create_Service(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, API_NAME, API_VERSION, SCOPES)
spreadsheet_id = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

spreadsheets_match_id = ['9647082','9979984']
spreadsheets_match_minute = [27,85]

para_enviar_conjunto = []

for (id,minute) in zip(spreadsheets_match_id, spreadsheets_match_minute):
    
    url = f'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/{id}/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
    incidents = response['incidents']
    list_of_goals = []

    if any(i['incidentType'] == 'goal' for i in response['incidents']):
        for incident in incidents:
            if (incident['incidentType'] == 'goal' and incident['time'] <= minute):
                list_of_goals.append(incident['time'])    
    else:
        list_of_goals.append([0])
    if (len(list_of_goals) == 0):
        list_of_goals.append([0])
    else:
        pass

    para_enviar_conjunto.append([list_of_goals[0]])
    print(para_enviar_conjunto)

worksheet_name = 'MaxLevel'
cell_range_insert = 'AC2:AC'
values = (
    (para_enviar_conjunto),
)
value_range_body = {
    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values': values
}

service.spreadsheets().values().append(
    spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id,
    valueInputOption='USER_ENTERED',
    range=worksheet_name + '!' + cell_range_insert,
    body=value_range_body
).execute()

print("Fim")
```

I'm trying to send these values to a google spreadsheet, but when trying to send, this error appears:

```
returned "Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {
  values {
    number_value: 21.0
  }
}". Details: "Invalid values[1][0]: list_value {
  values {
    number_value: 21.0
  }
}
">
```

What should I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, when the value of `print(send_spreadsheet)` is used for the method of spreadsheets.values.append, no error occurs. I cannot replicate your issue. I apologize for my poor skill. Can I ask you about the detailed information for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Hi mate @Tanaike, is there any email I could send a copy of my code to you? I wouldn't want to send it here.

Comment: It's a personal project that I honestly don't want to make public on a large scale.

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, can you provide the sample value for correctly retrieving your issue? Because when your issue cannot be replicated, unfortunately, I cannot think of the modification point. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Friend @Tanaike , I decided to publish the entire code because I really need help to solve the case.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I asked about the sample value of `value` in your question for correctly replicating your issue. Can you provide the sample value of `value`? For example, the sample value is `[[21], [79]]` for replicating your issue. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thats correct @Tanaike , I published the complete code to make it easier for you to analyze. the list ```para_enviar_conjunto = []``` created by the code and which will be sent to the worksheet has these values ```para_enviar_conjunto = [[21], [79]]```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I understood your issue. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: In your question, I thought that the tag of `google-sheets-api` is suitable rather than `google-api`. So I edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your script, `values = ((para_enviar_conjunto),)` is `([[21], [79]],)`. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. So in this case, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
value_range_body = {
    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values': values
}
```

#### To:

```
value_range_body = {
    'majorDimension': 'ROWS',
    'values': para_enviar_conjunto
}
```

- In this case, you can remove `values = ((para_enviar_conjunto),)`.